# How do I reference a complex html selector with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a project that is already using jQuery, so I'd like to stay in theme.

How can I reference the following selector and obtain the contents? **I've highlighted the fields text I'm after, below.**

Chrome reports the selector as:

```
#gv-field-10-43 > td
```

I have tried variations on the following, but both result in the variable returning empty or undefined:

```
jobNo = jQuery("#gv-field-10-id > td").text();
jobNo = jQuery("#gv-field-10-id > td").html();
```

```
<table class="example">
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="gv-field-10-id" class="gv-field-10-id">
            <th scope="row">
                <span class="gv-field-label">Entry ID</span>
            </th>
            <td>
                5602 <-- This is the text I'm trying to find
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: The problem is actually that this was closed with an improper reason. I have resolved the issue over the course of the past 12 hours and would be willing to offer a solution, and explanation, but cannot do so. The issue, to be clear, has nothing to do with the DOM not being loaded, and nothing to do with any document ready / load issues. The issue is actually with the way the object is being identified. @Quentin

Comment: @anakaine — You're wrong. The way it is being identified is absolutely fine: https://jsbin.com/huvanuzaga/1/edit?html,js,output (Possibly you have a different problem with some other code which is different to the code you asked about, but for the question you asked, the duplicate covers the only possible solutions).

Comment: Well, this is what has wound up working reliably. https://pastebin.com/ZRmXzrG6